# accessing Session variable from jquery , expanding/collapsing submenu

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to access a Session Variable from jquery to expand/collapse a submenu based on the `ul` index (using eq)

```
function initMenu() {
  $('#menu ul').hide();

  $('#menu ul:eq('**<%Session["Menu"]%>**')').show();

  $('#menu li a').click(
    function() {
      var checkElement = $(this).next();
      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        return false;
        }
      if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        return false;
        }
      }
    );
  }
$(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

using `$('#menu ul:eq(0)').show();`

This works perfectly, but I cannot get it to work using the session variable

Comment: What JS does that generate? `<%Session["Menu"]%>` needs to evaluate to a number.

Comment: Do View Source in the browser and look at the line `$('#menu ul:eq('**<%Session["Menu"]%>**')').show();` to see what is rendered into the markup. There is probably your clue. If you post what that script looks like here it would be clearer what the probelm is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<%= Session["Menu"] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not writing the session value to the page try

```
$('#menu ul:eq('<%:Session["Menu"]%>')').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll need to make an ajax call to return the session value you're looking for...

Something along this lines

```
var html = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "path to the file&act=something",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
```

In your file you should check for act=somethinhg and return the session value

responseText should now have your session value

Comment: Hmm i think I didn't got the question right... sorry if that's the case